# How to pass the seahorses in candy box 2

Tags: candy-box-2

I've been going in the ocean for a while, but now I've gotten to these seahorses. They shoot the magic, and I can dodge those, but I can never actually reach the seahorses themselves to kill them. How do I pass these creatures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use weapons with good range like the [`Monkey Wizard Staff`](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Monkey_Wizard_Staff) or the [`Octopus King's Crown with Jaspers`](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Octopus_King%27s_Crown) (the best I think)

Answer (score 1):

or if you just want to be simple, you can just use a fire ball and kill them off one by one